# opacity a:visited

Tags: html, css, opacity

I can't get opacity to work on a:visited hyperlinks in firefox or IE

If I set the background color of a:visited it will work fine, but the opactity will not set.

Any ideas?

Here is my css:

```
a.photo
{
    display: inline-block;
}
a.photo img
{
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
a:hover.photo img, 
a:active.photo img {
    background-color: #FF2D59;
    border: 1px solid #FF2D59;
}
a:visited.photo img 
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
a.small img
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 6px;
}


<a href="#" class="photo small">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg" alt="small photo hyperlink" />
</a>
```

I dont think there is anything wrong with the order of the CSS , becuase if I add a background color , it works just fine:

```
a:visited.photo img 
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background-color: Gray;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `a.photo:visited`?

Comment: @Joel Etherton: Classes and pseudo-classes can be arranged in any order, so `a:visited.photo` is fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.

This from IE's Developer Tools console. I'm pretty sure Firefox's shows a similar error.

Sorry. Not much can be done there.

Comment: You know, I never really understood this. Surely you can read the computedStyle.color and find visited links? I don't know...

Comment: I will leave this question unanswered just in case there is another solution.

Comment: It doesn't look likely. `document.querySelectorAll(":visited")` returns an empty list regardless of the presence or absence of visited links, so there's no way of finding those. I'll try searching for the colour style.

Comment: Attempting to get the `computedStyle` of the visited link returns the colour of a non-visited link. Sorry, but it looks like there's no workaround.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have tried changing different values and only things that can be changed are background color and border color.

Answer (score 4):

Since 2010, Mozilla browser limit the CSS properties that can be used to style visited links to :
- color, 
- background-color, 
- border-*-color
- outline-color
- and the color parts of the fill and stroke properties.

For any other parts of the style for visited links, the style for unvisited links is used instead. In addition, for the list of properties you can change above, you won’t be able to set rgba() or hsla() colors or transparent on them.

Source :
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/