# How to reduce opacity of images wrapped in visited links with CSS-only?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, visited

### Description

Visiting imgur.com several times a day, I would like to hide links/images I already viewed, in order to [reduce cognitive load](http://www.slideshare.net/msquareg/reconsidering-cognitive-load-in-web-based-instruction).

From what I read on [MDN Privacy and the :visited selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector#Limits_to_visited_link_styles) article there is some limitation to the pseudo selector `:visited`. So rules such as below won't work:

```css
:visited { 
   opacity: .1; /*don't work*/
}
```

#### Tested

I tried to define all images with null opacity then reset the one not visited, but same results :

```css
a img {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
a:not(:visited) img { /* don't work */
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

### Question

Is there a hack/way **using CSS-only** so that images are hidden or have reduce opacity **when being a child of a visited** link ?

CSS-only constrains is due to the use of [Firefox' add-on Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216164/opacity-avisited

Comment: I wan to style children of :visited, not the element itself

Comment: I found out that Mozilla limited styling of `:visited` selector to `color`, `background-color`, `border-color`, and `outline-color`. Read this useful article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/. However, I'm not sure about all the other browsers.