# Anchor tag with a css sprite image not changing on active

Tags: html, css, anchor, css-sprites

I have an icon attached to the anchor tag on hover i could able to change the image, but 
    clicking on the image the a:active is not applied .this problem is only when clicking the image not with the text.

css

```
.ctrls {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.ctrls:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ctrls .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://jstiles.com/temp/1360875952/ctrls/css-sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: 0px -144px;
}

.ctrls:hover .icon {
    background-position: 0px -252px;
}

.ctrls:active .icon {
    background-position: 0px -252px;
}
```

html

```
  <span> 
        <a href="#" class="ctrls" id="signal1"> <span class="icon"></span>Signal1</a>
        <a href="#" class="ctrls" id="signal2"> <span class="icon"></span>Signal2</a>
        <a href="#" class="ctrls" id="signal3"> <span class="icon"></span>Signal3</a>
    </span>
```

and also i have this code in two different div so the active state on one anchor tag should not change the another.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you have same background position for `:hover` and `:active`.

change it and it should work.

```
.ctrls:hover .icon {
    background-position: 0px -252px;
}

.ctrls:active .icon {
    background-position: 0px 0px; //change position
}
```

To change text-color use

```
    .ctrls:active{
        color:green;
    }
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6a27Z/4/)

`:visited` and `:link` styles can only differ by **color**. 
[Read this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216164/opacity-avisited)

Comment: it is working correctly on clicking over the text,the problem is only on click over the image

Comment: hover is working fine,the problem occurs only on active that to on click over the image(not text)

Comment: it is also working on clicking the image. pls see fiddle and click on image.

Comment: pls try it in eclipse its not working correctly the yellow image should stay even after the mouse is moved out of <a>tag