# How to make visited <article> element 0.5 opaque?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, opacity, visited

I am trying to make a visited "article" element on my site 0.5 opaque, so users know which ones they have clicked on in past sessions. I have tried this CSS:

```
article .card--listing:visited {opacity:0.5;}
```

but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Here is a link to a JSFiddle mockup I created
https://jsfiddle.net/v00cgvc8/

[Screenshot of my site's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT1WB.jpg)

Comment: you would have to make the anchor inside opaque as that is what can be visited

Comment: posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216164/opacity-avisited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a:visited links - opacity not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215684/avisited-links-opacity-not-working) - Due to the fact that you cannot change opacity using `:visited` you need to find another way targeting the `h2 / .card__title` directly when needed.

Answer (score 0):

*:visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were    not applied to :visited.*

So nothing can be done,using css.
For more info: [opacity-visited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216164/opacity-avisited) and 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215684/avisited-links-opacity-not-working)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendations how I could achieve what I am trying to do using php?